# Add input text in select option dropdown

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, html-select, dropdown

I would like to know how to add input text in the bottom to select dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text"/>
    </option>
  </select>
```

[image]

Comment: you can create custom select component

Comment: You can't but I suggest you to use bootstrap plugins like http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-select/ or write your custom HTML code using bootstrap components

Answer (score 1):

You may come up with a [typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples). Typeahead has the option to add what you type as a new item.

You can create your own component or you may use an existing one.